# run time error '-2147024809(80070057)' the specified value is out of range

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

Im trying to format a text box present in a slide in a PPT using VBA ;by taking the input values for properties of text box like font name,alignment etc from an Excel file.

```
Select Case Shp_new.Type
              
         Case MsoShapeType.msoTextBox      
            Shp_new.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name = "" & textboxrange.Cells(1, 1).Value & ""
            Shp_new.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = textboxrange.Cells(1, 4).Value 

End Select
```

But,it is throwing me the following error "run time error '-2147024809(80070057)' the specified value is out of range"  for text alignment property and moreover only when the value for text alignment is '-2'.

The Text alignment values that I have in my input excel file are as follows : 0,1,2,3,4,-2
these values in Excel file are generated by the following piece of code

```
Shp_new.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment
```

From the following post https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.textbox.textalign I was able to understand the type of alignment for the values:  0,1,2,3,4
But as per the doc, there is no such alignment type '-2' .
Not sure why it is giving me -2 value for few text boxes.

I feel that since there is no such alignment type -2 , it is throwing me an error.

But not sure what exactly is the cause of this error.Needed help in this regard

Comment: -2 is a valid value. It signifies "mixed" alignment. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.ppparagraphalignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.ppparagraphalignment)

Comment: Oh my bad i was looking into text alignment values.Thanks for sharing the doc @Porcupine911.Okay since it is a valid value is there any idea on what it is the cause of this error.It is throwing me error only when ever im encountering value = -2 in excel.

Comment: While "mixed" is a valid value, I think the problem is that you cannot assign a "mixed" alignment since it doesn't mean anything specific as far as I can tell. Therefore PPT complains with that error.

Comment: -2/Mixed tells you that the text in question has several different properties applied (for example, it might have several different fonts/boldness/etc.). Assigning Mixed makes no sense, though.

Answer (score 1):

"Mixed" alignment isn't a particularly clear instruction. It takes its meaning from the installed language. In other words, if you work in a language where the instruction makes sense you can use it. Reverse-engineered, if it doesn't work for you it doesn't make sense in the language in which you work.

[Click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.paragraph.alignment?view=word-pia) to refer to Microsoft's explanation, the short of which I copy for you below.

"Some of the constants listed above may not be available to you, depending on the language support (U.S. English, for example) that you’ve selected or installed."

Comment: And though that article applies to paragraph alignment in Word, not Excel or PowerPoint, most of the options are similar. Note that it doesn't include Mixed as one of the properties you can assign. It's not a matter of the installed language being wrong, it's that Mixed is, in effect, a read-only property, though not presented as such.